# web3.eth.personal.sign is not a function error when deployed on heroku

Tags: web3js, metamask, signature

I am building dApp with react as my front-end frame work, i encountered this error when I deployed on Heroku, sign function doesn't work and it displays that error, specifically `TypeError: A.t2.sign.call is not a function` on the console... on local-host tho it works perfectly fine.. other than signing everything works well like contract interaction, only the signing got that error.. need some help thanks